# create increment index for each group, starting row conditional on other column

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's assume I have a dataset similar to this:

```
library(tidyverse)

country <- c(rep("Germany", 9), rep("Greece", 9), rep("Turkey", 9), rep("Austria", 9))
date <- rep(seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2012-04-15'),by='days'), 4)
gyros_eaten <- c(lag(1:3, n = 2, default = 0), floor(runif(6, min=1, max=4)),
                 lag(1:6, n = 5, default = 0), floor(runif(3, min=1, max=4)),
                 lag(1:2, n = 1, default = 0), floor(runif(7, min=1, max=4)),
                 lag(1:3, n = 2, default = 0), floor(runif(6, min=1, max=4)))
df <- data.frame(country, date, gyros_eaten)
```

I want to create a new column, name it `days_since_first_local_gyros`, which would tell me how many days have passed since eating the **first** gyros, **in that particular country**. That is, it would take the value of zero if no gyros was eaten yet, or if on that day I ate my first gyros in e.g. Greece. After that, it would run from 1 to infinity, increasing by 1 on each day. Hence each group (i.e. country) would have a distinct index, and I have rows for each possible country x day dyads in my dataset, within a particular time range.

How should I create this column? I assume it's some combination of `case when`, `group_by` and `lag`, but i just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could get the first `date` where `gyros_eaten > 0` and subtract all the dates from that date in the `country`. We use `pmax` to keep max value of 0 in `days_since_first_local_gyros`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(country, date) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(days_since_first_local_gyros = pmax(as.integer(date - 
                            date[which.max(gyros_eaten > 0)]), 0))

#   country date       gyros_eaten days_since_first_local_gyros
#   <chr>   <date>           <dbl>                        <dbl>
# 1 Austria 2012-04-07           0                            0
# 2 Austria 2012-04-08           0                            0
# 3 Austria 2012-04-09           1                            0
# 4 Austria 2012-04-10           1                            1
# 5 Austria 2012-04-11           1                            2
# 6 Austria 2012-04-12           2                            3
# 7 Austria 2012-04-13           2                            4
# 8 Austria 2012-04-14           2                            5
# 9 Austria 2012-04-15           3                            6
#10 Germany 2012-04-07           0                            0
# … with 26 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I need!